# Updated to Xcode 10.1 on Mojave and now my app always asks to use the microphone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, avaudiosession, macos-mojave

I am running a AVAudioSession which I suspect is activating the microphone request, but I only use it for sounds and music. When running Xcode 10.1 Simulator on macOS **Mojave**, why does it activate a request to access the microphone? I haven't written a single line to even ask access to it. My app doesn't need access to it nor do I want it to.  Here's the code to play the music:

```
AVAudioSession *title = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[title setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[title setActive:YES error:nil];


//MUSIC
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music_nature" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
titleMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];

titleMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
[titleMusic setVolume:1.0];
[titleMusic play];
```

If I comment out the above code, I will no longer get a request for the microphone.  But then I don't have any music.

Sample project: https://github.com/Coeur/StackOverflow53109911
(you need macOS **Mojave** to reproduce the issue)

[image: Screen shot demonstrating error message]

Comment: Please share the code you have for sound/music playback.

Comment: @ThEuSeFuL Done.

Comment: Hmmm...same here. Upgraded to 10.1 and now it is asking.

Comment: @Cœur. I have changed it to [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]] and no change.

Comment: @Cœur AVPlayer doesn't seem to work?  How would I write this?  I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: @Cœur. I have Xcode version "Version 10.1 (10B61)". and I'm running Mac OS Mojave version 10.14 (18A391)

Comment: @MrCoinOp yes, I've updated your question now that we've clarified the origin of the issue. You may self-delete some of the obsolete comments.

Comment: @Cœur. Just read your above post.  So it's a Mojave bug and not an iOS bug.  That's a massive relief!  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I also got this problem recently on an audiostreaming app that has been working ok for years without the microphone access popup. It happens when you try to get the AVAudioSession.

Update: **Seems like Xcode 10.2 (beta 1) solves this by only asking the first time and then remembering your answer.**

Update2: Xcode 10.2 is now out and only asks the first time.

Comment: Same here. I have tried setting different `categories` and `modes` but they all do it.