# iOS Simulator would like to access microphone every time

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, macos-mojave

Since the update to macOS Mojave, I get this alert every time I run on the simulator:

> "<AppName>" would like to access the microphone.

It is stopping the simulator from running!
How can I stop it?

[image: Mojave security alert!]

Comment: This Support does not help to resolve the issue.

Comment: I got this alert on my app. My app definitely isn't requesting to use the microphone.

Comment: This is a known bug

Comment: @russbishop how do you know it's a known bug?

Comment: @kikeenrique Because I wrote the bug.

Comment: @russbishop will this be fixed in latest version 10.2 ?

Comment: Yes this is fixed in 10.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated to Xcode 10.1 on Mojave and now my app always asks to use the microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109911/updated-to-xcode-10-1-on-mojave-and-now-my-app-always-asks-to-use-the-microphone)

Comment: @russbishop, my app doesn't use the microphone at all, but this still pops up when running on 10.2

Comment: @russbishop No it's not.

Comment: @russbishop Does that mean you implemented the bug or you wrote a bug report? :) (You see as a programmer I know very well that bugs are implemented but if you prefer you can change the question to be are you an Apple dev and wrote the code with the bug in it)

Comment: I wrote the code. And by "fixed" I mean you can approve access once and it covers all processes in all simulators. You'll still get prompted that one time.

Comment: It doesn't help, because without permission for microphone a simulator use microphone :)))

Answer (score 26):

What worked for me was to change the Hardware Audio Input to **Internal Microphone**.
What I believe happen is that when you give access it changes the audio input to your headphones or macbook. 
My concern was that I am watching a tutorial and it keeps changing the audio frequency and it kept bothering me.

[image: Internal Microphone]

Answer (score 11):

My app does not use microphone, it only plays videos. I was able to fix the alert popup by restricting Microphone access for Xcode in Security & Privacy -> Microphone

Comment: and what does give you? it still asks you all the time even if microphone is unchecked there for xcode

Answer (score 6):

This has been resolved in Xcode 10.2 Beta. Installing the beta should also fix it for older Xcode versions since CoreSimulator.framework will be upgraded (and remains backwards-compatible with older Xcodes).

The new behavior prompts for Microphone access *once* on your Mac. That approval (or denial) covers all processes in all Simulator runtimes including new runtimes downloaded and new Xcodes installed after the initial approval prompt.

The normal TCC rules continue to apply inside Simulator. Your app must have the relevant Info.plist keys with a microphone usage description if you actually attempt to record audio. This will continue to generate an iOS TCC prompt inside that specific Simulator. If your app only plays audio then no TCC prompts will be generated by iOS.

Comment: Is there a way to dismiss the prompt when running automated UI tests? My tests pass on my local machine after I've manually dismissed the prompt once, but they fail when using a CI service where they run in a fresh container every time.

Comment: See radar 48882952 :-)

Comment: Xcode 12 still has this bug, just... different. First time run simulator (with xcode) opens mic. If I close the simulator and run it again with xcode it no longer accesses the mic. creepy if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed this for me was to **Not Allow** the microphone access for xcode. After selecting this option the popup no longer appeared after further restarts.

Unfortunately the previous fixes did not work as Xcode was not available in:

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Microphone (No Xcode listed here)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to "Security & Privacy" Settings on macOS
2. Select "Microphone" on the left panel
3. On the right panel disable the option for Xcode

Comment: Xcode does not appear in the list on my Macbook Pro. MacOs 10.14.2.

Comment: Mine does have Xcode in the microphone settings, however, it does not fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two issues here: microphone access for both Xcode and the app itself.

Your app (or a UITest) can prompt (fail) for either or both, though not always on same run.

Both of these dialogs must be approved to allow access, after which the permission persists between Xcode and Simulator resets or restarts.

You can confirm access has been approved for Xcode in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy-> Microphone, where you should see the Xcode in the UI.

The app itself, approved or not, won't appear in the UI here, however.

If you are unsure it the app has been approved, reset all the microphone permissions with 'tccutil reset Microphone' in the Terminal, and re-run your app/test, until both dialogs have been shown and approved.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the app on the simulator not from Xcode, but from the app's icon. 
The dialogue will appear one more time. Answer it and it won't appear again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Keep asking it every time the code changes.

Answer (score -2):

In Simulator Go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy and then press "Reset Warnings" when asked.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this section, But Xcode not showing there for me.
Why?

Comment: Please check under system preferences not of Xcode.

Comment: simply click on "Don't Allow" on simulator

Comment: @Mani Too bad it asks every single time I run the app every single day. It's annoying. Putting Don't Allow doesn't do anything besides remove the popup until next build. It always asks the first time a sound plays in the app.

Comment: I have updated my solution to new one currently working for me. Please try this one