# IOS UI Testing: how to dismiss a series of system alerts( microphone access ) via code using fastlane snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, xcuitest, fastlane-snapshot

I use mac mojave 10.14.3 and react-native version - 0.59.1, fastlane latest version. I tried to run the fastlane screenshot via ios xcuitest But I couldn't dismiss the system alert. I have attached my code and alert screen

Could you please help me

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "System Dialog") {
        (alert) -> Bool in
        let okButton = alert.buttons["OK"]
        if okButton.exists {
          okButton.tap()
        }

        let allowButton = alert.buttons["Allow"]
        if allowButton.exists {
          allowButton.tap()
        }

        return true
      }

      app.tap()
      snapshot("04EndRecord")
```

this is my alert and app. this alert shows outside of the app, then how can i handle that?

[image: Microphone access alert]

Comment: Which version of Xcode is being used?

Comment: You can use launch arguments of fastlane in the code to disable the system alerts to  popup while snapshot is run [Check this link](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/snapshot/#launch-arguments)

Comment: @Dan - XCode version - 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: Thanks @PavanKotesh This system alert automatically triggered after a user interaction. any example for this launch arguments?

Comment: There must be some code which triggers the system alert. Can't be automatic. For example push notifications alert is triggered by registering for APNS.

Comment: This is an issue with XCode 10.1. Upgrading to 10.2 will not prompt you for the microphone continuously - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285441/ios-simulator-would-like-to-access-microphone-every-time

Answer (score 0):

Are the system alerts automatically triggered or after a user interaction ?
You should add your InterruptionMonitor before the dialogs are triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This system alert automatically triggered after a user interaction.

Comment: Did you try to put the `InterruptionMonitor` instance before the user interaction has been done ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue a few months ago. It appeared when I wanted to use sounds in the app. I disabled sounds during running UI tests.

Can you apply the same process to your app ?