# Repeated request for microphone permission on iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, macos-mojave

I'm working with Xcode 10.1 (10B61) on an app that needs permission to use the microphone.
(Almost) Every time I start the app from Xcode (in simulator) I get a system popup:

> "Appname" would like to access the microphone
>   "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description"">

It doesn't matter if I select "Don't Allow" or "OK". This message keeps popping up.
How can I fix it?

## Update [fixed]

This issue seems to be fixed in Xcode 10.2

Comment: I'm having the same problem after updating to Xcode 10.1 (10B61). It's driving me batty.

Comment: More specifically, the Simulator doesn't remember that you once granted access to these resources (not just the Microphone, but Photos, network, etc.)
This is tedious.

Comment: What is more concerning is if AdMob listening to the Microphone on the real device. Are they selling the captured audio to advertisement companies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updated to Xcode 10.1 on Mojave and now my app always asks to use the microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109911/updated-to-xcode-10-1-on-mojave-and-now-my-app-always-asks-to-use-the-microphone)

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of this following this steps:

1. Go to "Security & Privacy" Settings on macOS.
2. Select "Microphone" on the left panel.
3. Uncheck the Xcode option on the right panel.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have Xcode unchecked and still get the popup. Even restarted everything for good measure and verified the option is still unchecked.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, Xcode does not appear in the list.

Comment: This did work for me for a while but it just asked again.

Answer (score 1):

After looking for a workaround this one seems to fix it for me:
In Simulator go to Settings > Your App > Disable the Microphone Access

Update:
Not solving this issue but might be helpful:
You can dismiss the popup via Esc key - that should be way faster than clicking a button

Comment: That isn’t in the Settings app for me (I am using iPad 2, since I still support iOS 9).

Comment: @DavidDunham I also had that issue once. Did you try deleting the app and or if that doesn't help reseting the simulator?

Comment: Xcode does not appear in the Microphone list on my macbook pro, macos 10.14.2. I fixed by not allowing the app access to the microphone, afterwhich the popup no longer appeared. This may not be an ideal fix but it worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

Unfortunately it looks like the following procedure is just a temporary fix. After some time the dialog started appearing again. Repeating the procedure fixes it for an additional period of time.

---

I had the same problem and what helped in my case was disabling and then re-enabling microphone permissions in the the Simulator.

**Steps to fix:**

- go to Settings app in the Simulator
- find your app settings page within the Settings app
- disable microphone permission (or any other permission that is causing trouble)
- re-enable microphone permissions

After this procedure, the microphone permissions dialog stopped appearing every time I would run the app.

**Note that I did run the app with the permissions disabled and navigated to the point where permissions are required before re-enabling them (but I don't think that's required).**

Hope this helps, it did in my case.

Comment: I haven't tried this, as what worked for me was just not allowing access to the microphone, then it stopped asking. As long as I allowed access, the app would request every time. But this does look like the correct solution, thanks.

Comment: My app's settings do not mention the microphone. Also, under settings->privacy-microphone no apps have requested access.

Comment: Interesting, but you are requesting microphone access for your app?

Answer (score -3):

Another work around is to check if the app is running in the simulator and disable the audio code:

```
struct Platform {
  static var isSimulator: Bool {
    return TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR != 0
  }
}
```