# iOS Simulator crashes on microphone permission request

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator, microphone

My environment:

- permission_handler 3.0.0
- Flutter v1.2.1
- OSX High Sierra 10.13.6
- Xcode version 10.1.

My app is crashing when I request the permission for microphone in the iOS simulator.

```dart
PermissionStatus mic = await PermissionHandler()
    .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.microphone);
print('microphone permission? ${mic.toString()}');
try {
    if (mic != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.microphone]);
    }
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

No error is thrown or caught, but in the flutter debug console, I see:

```
flutter: microphone permission? PermissionStatus.unknown
Lost connection to device.
```

This means that `checkPermissionStatus()` returned `unknown`. But then when I request the permission, the application crashes. I have not been able to try this on a real iPhone. Everything works perfectly on the Android simulator.

I've seen there were some problems in Xcode 10.1 with the microphone:

- [iOS Simulator would like to access microphone every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285441/ios-simulator-would-like-to-access-microphone-every-time)
- [Repeated request for microphone permission on iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432769/repeated-request-for-microphone-permission-on-ios-simulator)

**What I've tried**

- Fresh build with `flutter clean`
- Changing the simulator microphone input in Hardware > Audio Input

I could try to upgrade to Xcode 10.2, but I'd need to get mojave first. Trying to avoid that if possible as it might not even fix the issue. I can also try using a real iPhone device instead of the simulator. Would love to get the simulator not crashing, though.

Is anyone able to grant microphone permission in Xcode `10.1`/`10.2` simulator using `permission_handler: 3.0.0`? What about another flutter permission plugin?

Comment: I know nothing about Flutter, but I think you've answered your own question. There are many things that just don't work on the simulator, and this could very well be one of them.

Comment: @matt but looking at the stack overflow questions I linked, it seems like people were at least able to grant microphone permission without the app crashing

Comment: Well I’m suggesting maybe flutter changes the equation

Comment: For sure you can use a mic in a simulator (it will use mac mic).
Try to click 2 times in home button (to invoke Siri) and check if Siri works correctly just to be sure that everything is ok with your mac. Maybe your mic is blocked or so.

Comment: You will definitely find that your error lies in the info.plist file. Open runner.xcworkspace and navigate to the info.plist file and add permission for the microphone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you have added the correct entries to the `Info.plist` file (for Flutter projects this file is located in the `ios/Runner/` folder).

To access the microphone you will need to add the following lines in between the `<dict>` tags:

```xml
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>this application needs access to the microphone</string>
```

More information can be found [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW25)

And a complete example of an `Info.plist` can be found [here.](https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/example/ios/Runner/Info.plist)

Comment: Yup! This was it. I added the `UIBackgroundModes->audio`, but not the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`.